# Minimum of empty Seq is infinite, Why?

Tags: raku

I'm working on this weeks PerlWChallenge.

> You are given an array of integers @A. Write a script to create an
> array that represents the smaller element to the left of each
> corresponding index. If none found then use 0.

Here's my approach:

```
my @A = (7, 8, 3, 12, 10);
my $L = @A.elems - 1;

say gather for 1 .. $L -> $i { take @A[ 0..$i-1 ].grep( * < @A[$i] ).min };
```

Which kinda works and outputs:

```
(7 Inf 3 3)
```

The Infinity obviously comes from the empty grep. Checking:

```
> raku -e "().min.say"
Inf
```

But why is the minimum of an empty Seq Infinity? If anything it should be -Infinity. Or zero?

It's probably a good idea to test for the empty sequence anyway.

I ended up using

```
take .min with @A[ 0..$i-1 ].grep( * < @A[$i] ) or 0
```

or

```
take ( @A[ 0..$i-1 ].grep( * < @A[$i] ) or 0 ).min
```

Comment: That may be a bug, the docs don't state what the `min` of an empty list should return I'd argue for `-Inf` as a valid result.

Comment: Meanwhile here's a thought to avoid that. If `@a[0..$i].min == @a[$i]` then you can return `0`.

Comment: I think this is even more problematic for `my int @a; say @a.min; # Inf`, as that returns a value that can actually not be represented by a native `int`.  So I guess this warrants a problem solving ticket, also for `max` and `minmax`.  FWIW, as a test, I changed these return values to `Nil`, and that causes spectest breakage.  So at least the current behaviour is enshrined in tests.

Comment: I currently consider what `min` is currently doing to be at, er, minimum, consistent with: ❶ mathematical treatments of numbers; ❷ python's treatment of numbers; ❸ Raku's carefully chosen default numeric type, for a carefully chosen definition of "default numeric type", which is double floats, aka `Num`.

Comment: It's taking me a while to find simple suitable links/quotes, which I'm thinking/hoping will be `#perl6` or `#perl6-dev` IRC discussion from a decade or so ago, or at least pointers to corresponding python discussions that I'm confident will have occurred. If/when I find decent discussion I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen My current thinking is along the lines of `+@issues-related-to-this-SO-needing-solutions == any 1..3;`, where potential problems are: ❶ doc; ❷ `min`/`max` of `int` values; ❸ the same for `str` values. Part of ❶ might just about conceivably be ❶: reminding creators  of custom types whose values have a `cmp` ordering to set their `min`/`max` identity values if they don't want `Inf`.

Comment: The distillation of the *math* reasoning for choosing the identity value is `operation(identity, x) = x`. That is to say, what is the value of `identity` such that `min identity, x` returns `x` for all `x`? For `min`, it's `Inf`, because `min Inf, x` will always be the same as `x`, even if `x` is itself `Inf`. I'll delete this and my other above comments when I move it to my answer.

Comment: Afaict at this early juncture of my investigation, with NumPy, applying the `min` function to an empty array returns an empty array.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, `Inf` works out quite well in the face of further operations. For example, consider a case where we have a list of lists, and we want to find the minimum across all of them. We can do this:

```
my @a = [3,1,3], [], [-5,10];
say @a>>.min.min
```

And it will just work, since `(1, Inf, -5).min` comes out as -5. Were `min` to instead have `-Inf` as its value, then it'd get this wrong. It will also behave reasonably in comparisons, e.g. `if @a.min > @b.min { }`; by contrast, an undefined value will warn.

Comment: .oO ( Play: "Identity crisis". Act II. Scene: jnthn's vacation villa. Stage right, `-Inf` exclaims "I will always oppose `Inf`!" as jnthn, sipping from his cup of tea, shows him the door. At the same time as he exits, `0` sneaks in, apparently unseen by jnthn, and relaxes on the sofa, smirking as she waits for jnthn to turn around. Staring at `-Inf`'s back, jnthn lets out a sigh, and then smiles. The audience holds their breath, as it dawns on them that [jnthn is a head of the game](https://github.com/masak/alma/blob/3963dee02b28b488b09b398ff14e19992b3e19f7/documentation/bond-pastiche.md)... )

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** `say min` displays `Inf`.

---

`min` is, or at least behaves like, a reduction.

---

Per [the doc for reduction of a `List`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/reduce#class_List):

> When the list contains no elements, an exception is thrown, unless `&with` is an operator with a known identity value (e.g., the identity value of `infix:<+>` is `0`).

---

Per [the doc for `min`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/min#(Any)_routine_min):

> a comparison `Callable` can be specified with the named argument `:by`

`by` is `min`'s spelling of `with`.

---

To easily see the "identity value" of an operator/function, call it without any arguments:

```
say min # Inf
```

---

Imo the underlying issue here is one of many unsolved wide challenges of documenting Raku. Perhaps comments here in this SO about doc would best focus on the narrow topic of solving the problem just for `min` (and maybe `max` and `minmax`).

Comment: I think historically the identity values for `min`, `max` where determined before there was a thing such as `Nil`.  Since the current behaviour is enshrined in spectest, changing this behaviour would at least require a language level change.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I'll search for related discussions. I've been doing similar investigations, perhaps a thousand, for about a decade. I spend from a few minutes to a decade and counting elapsed time for each investigation. For almost all I've found deep spot on discussion, and a carefully considered design decision. In almost all cases the decision seems better than alternatives discussed then or now. In this instance the *math* definition of `min` of an empty list of numbers is infinity. That said, Raku numerics don't slavishly follow math; `int`s can't store `Inf`; and what about strings?

Comment: Indeed.  So `Nil` in hindsight feels more appropriate now.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Is that hindsight though? If you're saying you recall the discussions in sufficient detail to see the flaw in thinking, then fair enough. I have a strong sense that there *would* have been discussions, and almost certainly a good decision. And a vague recollection that there *were* discussions I've encountered over the years which included the details relevant to this SO. But until I remind myself of enough of the details of those discussions, and get to mull them at least overnight, I'm sceptical that `Nil` would be a better *default* `min` identity value than `Inf`.

Comment: Well, I wasn't actually around for these discussions, if I remember correctly.  Which implies these decisions were made *before* the semantics of `Nil` were finalized.  So it never entered the discussion then.  Again, as far as I remember :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think, there is inspiration from
[infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Infima_and_suprema_of_real_numbers)
(the greatest lower bound). Let we have the set of integers (or real
numbers) and add there the greatest element `Inf` and the lowest `-Inf`.
Then infimum of the empty set (as the subset of the previous set) is the
greatest element `Inf`. (Every element satisfies that is smaller than
any element of the empty set and `Inf` is the greatest element that
satisfies this.) Minimum and infimum of any nonempty finite set of real
numbers are equal.

Similarly, `min` in Raku works as infimum for some `Range`.

```
1 ^.. 10
andthen .min;   #1
```

but `1` is not from `1 ^.. 10`, so `1` is not minimum, but it is infimum
of the range.

It is useful for some algorithm, see [the answer by Jonathan
Worthington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340282/545808) or

```
q{3 1 3
  -2
  --
  -5 10
}.lines
andthen .map: *.comb( /'-'?\d+/ )».Int # (3, 1, 3), (-2,), (), (-5, 10)
andthen .map: *.min                    # 1,-2,Inf,-5
andthen .produce: &[min]
andthen .fmt: '%2d',','                # 1,-2,-2,-5
```

Answer (score 1):

this (from the [docs](https://docs.raku.org/type/Range#method_min)) makes sense to me

```
method min(Range:D:)
Returns the start point of the range.

say (1..5).min;                                   # OUTPUT: «1␤» 
say (1^..^5).min;                                 # OUTPUT: «1␤»
```

and I think the infinimum idea is quite a good mnemonic for the excludes case which also could be 5.1^.. , 5.0001^.. etc.